# How to call layers within TimeDistributed wrapper in a keras program

Tags: keras

I want to call layers from the 'sentEncoder' model within the second TimeDistributed wrapper in a trained Keras model with the given architecture, to create another Keras model for making intermediate predictions. It is fairly simple to call layers from the 'docEncoder' model, but how do I access the layers in sentEncoder after training 'docEncoder'?

```python
l2_reg = regularizers.l2(reg_param)
sentence_input = Input(shape=(MAX_SENT_LENGTH,), dtype='int32')
embedding_layer = get_embedding_layer(embedding_dim=embedding_dim, embedding_matrix=embedding_matrix,
                                      max_num_words=max_num_words, max_sent_length=max_sent_length,
                                      reg_param=reg_param)
embedded_sequences = embedding_layer(sentence_input)
l_lstm = Bidirectional(GRU(gru_units, return_sequences=True))(embedded_sequences)
l_dense = TimeDistributed(Dense(2*gru_units, use_bias=True,
                                bias_initializer='zero',
                                kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                                activation='tanh'))(l_lstm)
l_att = AttLayer()(l_dense)
sentEncoder = Model(sentence_input, l_att)
print(sentEncoder.summary())

doc_input = Input(shape=(max_sents, max_sent_length), dtype='int32')
review_encoder = TimeDistributed(sentEncoder)(doc_input)
l_lstm_sent = Bidirectional(GRU(gru_units, return_sequences=True))(review_encoder)
l_dense_sent = TimeDistributed(Dense(2*gru_units, use_bias=True,
                                     bias_initializer='zero',
                                     kernel_initializer='glorot_uniform',
                                     activation='tanh'))(l_lstm_sent)
l_att_sent = AttLayer()(l_dense_sent)
preds = Dense(n_classes, activation='sigmoid', kernel_regularizer=l2_reg)(l_att_sent)
docEncoder = Model(doc_input, preds)
```

Answer (score 1):

The weights from a layer within the TimeDistributed wrapper can be extracted like this:

```
sent_att_u_weights = model.layers[4].get_weights()[0]
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like the following to set it trainable again:

```
for layer in docEncoder.layers[0].layer.layers:
layer.trainable=True
```

First you access in your main model the `TimeDistributed` wrapped `sentEncoder` as a layer, then the layers inside it.